# PostgreSQL : cannot insert into table due to permissions

Tags: postgresql-9.5

I am using PostgreSQL 9.5.

I have a database with several schemas and I want a user to be able to do select, update, insert, delete on all the tables inside one of these schemas.

I have used to following PSQL code to create the role :

---

```
DROP ROLE IF EXISTS myrole ;
CREATE ROLE myrole WITH 
    LOGIN
    PASSWORD 'myrole' 
    NOSUPERUSER INHERIT NOCREATEDB NOCREATEROLE NOREPLICATION
    ;
GRANT a_user_group TO myrole;

ALTER ROLE myrole VALID UNTIL 'infinity' ;

 \connect mydatabase ;

GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON SCHEMA myschema TO myrole;
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA myschema TO myrole;
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON ALL SEQUENCES IN SCHEMA myschema TO myrole;

ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES IN SCHEMA myschema  GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON SEQUENCES TO myrole ;
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES IN SCHEMA myschema  GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON TABLES TO myrole ;

GRANT USAGE, SELECT ON ALL SEQUENCES IN SCHEMA public TO myrole ;
```

---

I thought that would ought to be enough but I cannot do INSERT with this user. I can only do SELECT and I am pretty sure that it's because the group a_user_group has this privilege.

I cannot find how to make this works. Any idea ?

Comment: I was forgetting to mention the error messages. 

When I try to delete / insert :
ERROR:  permission denied for relation <table name>

When I try to insert

Comment: I noticed I made a small mistake : the error message is
ERROR:  permission denied for sequence <table name>_pkid_seq

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved !

After pgAdmin crashed each time I was trying to access the incriminated sequence with the aformentioned role, and reading the pgAdmin error, I started to suspect the state of the role had a trouble.

So I deleted the role using

```
    REVOKE ALL PRIVILEGES ON SCHEMA traitements FROM zones_delaissees_traitements ;
REVOKE ALL PRIVILEGES ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA traitements FROM zones_delaissees_traitements ;
REVOKE ALL PRIVILEGES ON ALL SEQUENCES IN SCHEMA traitements FROM zones_delaissees_traitements ;
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES IN SCHEMA traitements  REVOKE ALL PRIVILEGES ON SEQUENCES FROM zones_delaissees_traitements ;
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES IN SCHEMA traitements  REVOKE ALL PRIVILEGES ON TABLES FROM zones_delaissees_traitements ;
DROP ROLE IF EXISTS zones_delaissees_traitements ;
```

And created it again, and now it works !